# how to manage transaction when one thread is dependent on previous thread in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

Thread should work on the bases of first come first serve approach, and when previous thread commit then next thread will start their execution.

Comment: Imagine the number of computers doing nothin would be necessary to serve all the http requests if that's how it worked! The whole point of threads is to execute concurrently, not sequentially.

Comment: Can you give a use case with sample code?

Comment: I am running an application in which multiple players are playing at a same time, and one player output is input for the next player. So, in this case, previous player should finish their job then the next player will get the control.

Comment: Message queue may be a solution to achieve this.